# Setting a count variable given binary flags in Python (pandas dataframe)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with layout according to below, **not** including "flag_common":

```
cat      flag_1   flag_2  flag_3   pop      state       year    flag_common
value1   1        0       0        1.5      Ohio        2000    1
value3   1        1       0        1.7      Ohio        2001    1
value2   1        1       0        3.6      Ohio        2002    1
value11  0        1       0        2.4      Nevada      2001    2
value5   0        0       0        2.9      Nevada      2002    0
value9   0        0       1        11.1     New York    2003    3
value13  0        0       0        23.4     New York    2004    0
value10  1        1       0        0.1      California  2009    1
value7   0        0       0        0.3      California  2010    0
value14  0        1       1        1.1      California  2009    2
```

The column "flag_common" should be set by looking at the the binary flags and inserting value 1-3 depending if the flags are 1 or 0. When two of the flag are set to 1 for same row, the flag with the lowest number is inserted into "flag_common". This has to be dynamic, being able to handle flag_1 to "flag_n".

I have sort of solved it using an row iteration method and a for-loop, but my data is very big and its becomes quite slow, so I hope there is a "pythonic" way to write this which is vectorized.

Code for data frame is below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'state': ['Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Ohio', 'Nevada', 'Nevada', 'New York', 'New York', 'California', 'California', 'California'],
                 'year' : [2000, 2001, 2002, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2009, 2010, 2009],
                 'pop' : [1.5, 1.7, 3.6, 2.4, 2.9, 11.1, 23.4, 0.1, 0.3, 1.1],
               'cat' : ['value1', 'value3', 'value2', 'value11', 'value5', 'value9', 'value13', 'value10', 'value7', 'value14'],
               'flag_1' : [1, 1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0],
               'flag_2' : [0, 1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1],
               'flag_3' : [0, 0, 0, 0,0,1,0,0,0, 1]
                })
```

Thanks i advance for any thoughts and suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) of `columns` in subset by columns `flag_1`, `flag_2` and `flag_3`, then find positions by list comprehension with [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html).

But positions with all `0` values are not `0`, but `flag_1`. So use [numpy.where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for correct it.

```
#get min value of columns 'flag_1','flag_2','flag_3'
print df[['flag_1','flag_2','flag_3']].idxmax(axis=1)
0    flag_1
1    flag_1
2    flag_1
3    flag_2
4    flag_1
5    flag_3
6    flag_1
7    flag_1
8    flag_1
9    flag_2
dtype: object

#get position of flag
print df.columns.get_loc('flag_1')
1

#get positions all flags
flag = [df.columns.get_loc(k) for k in df[['flag_1','flag_2','flag_3']].idxmax(axis=1)] 
print flag
[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2]

#alternative solution for positions of flags - last digit has to be number
print [int(x[-1]) for x in df[['flag_1','flag_2','flag_3']].idxmax(axis=1)]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2]
```

```
#if all values in 'flag_1','flag_2','flag_3' are 0, get 0 else flag
df['new'] = np.where((df[['flag_1','flag_2','flag_3']].sum(axis=1)) == 0, 0, flag)
print df
       cat  flag_1  flag_2  flag_3   pop       state  year  flag_common  new
0   value1       1       0       0   1.5        Ohio  2000            1    1
1   value3       1       1       0   1.7        Ohio  2001            1    1
2   value2       1       1       0   3.6        Ohio  2002            1    1
3  value11       0       1       0   2.4      Nevada  2001            2    2
4   value5       0       0       0   2.9      Nevada  2002            0    0
5   value9       0       0       1  11.1    New York  2003            3    3
6  value13       0       0       0  23.4    New York  2004            0    0
7  value10       1       1       0   0.1  California  2009            1    1
8   value7       0       0       0   0.3  California  2010            0    0
9  value14       0       1       1   1.1  California  2009            2    2
```

EDIT:

You can also dynamically check columns with text `flag`:

```
#get columns where first value before _ is text 'flag'
cols = [x for x in df.columns if x.split('_')[0] == 'flag']
print cols
['flag_1', 'flag_2', 'flag_3']

#get min value of columns 'flag_1','flag_2','flag_3'
print df[cols].idxmax(axis=1)
0    flag_1
1    flag_1
2    flag_1
3    flag_2
4    flag_1
5    flag_3
6    flag_1
7    flag_1
8    flag_1
9    flag_2
dtype: object

#get positions of flag
print df.columns.get_loc('flag_1')
1

#get positions all flags
flag = [df.columns.get_loc(k) for k in df[cols].idxmax(axis=1)] 
print flag
[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2]

#alternative solution for positions of flags - last digit has to be number
print [int(x[-1]) for x in df[cols].idxmax(axis=1)]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2]
```

```
#if all values in 'flag_1','flag_2','flag_3' are 0, get 0 else flag
df['new'] = np.where((df[cols].sum(axis=1)) == 0, 0, flag)
print df
       cat  flag_1  flag_2  flag_3   pop       state  year  new
0   value1       1       0       0   1.5        Ohio  2000    1
1   value3       1       1       0   1.7        Ohio  2001    1
2   value2       1       1       0   3.6        Ohio  2002    1
3  value11       0       1       0   2.4      Nevada  2001    2
4   value5       0       0       0   2.9      Nevada  2002    0
5   value9       0       0       1  11.1    New York  2003    3
6  value13       0       0       0  23.4    New York  2004    0
7  value10       1       1       0   0.1  California  2009    1
8   value7       0       0       0   0.3  California  2010    0
9  value14       0       1       1   1.1  California  2009    2
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I wanted, and performance wise its really good!

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck! I add one improvement to solution, maybe help.